# Count occurrences in lisp

Tags: lisp, repl-printed-representation

I'm trying to make a code in lisp to count occurrences of atoms in a list in lisp.
The problem is the code works for all atoms except the atom `()`, which appears as `NIL`.
Example in the code:

```
(defun flatten (list_) 
    (cond   ((atom list_) (list list_))
            ((null list_) NIL)
            (t (append (flatten (car list_)) (flatten (cdr list_))) )
    )
)

(defun toUniqueList (list_ out) 
    (cond   ((null list_) NIL)
            ((not (member (car list_) out)) (append (list (car list_)) (toUniqueList (cdr list_) (append (list (car list_)) out)) ))
            (t (toUniqueList (cdr list_) out))
    )
)

(defun countOccurences (list_ x) 
    (cond   ((null list_) 0)
            ((eql (car list_) x) (+ (countOccurences (cdr list_) x) 1))
            (t (countOccurences (cdr list_) x))
    )

)

(defun countOccurencesAll (list_) 
    (setq flatList (flatten list_))
    (setq parsed (toUniqueList flatList '()))
    (setq result '())
    (dolist (x parsed)
        (setq result (append result (list (list x (countOccurences flatList x)) ))))
    result
)

(write (countOccurencesAll '(x y z 4.6 (a x) () (5 z x) ())))
; ((X 3) (Y 1) (Z 2) (4.6 1) (A 1) (NIL 5) (5 1))
```

Any idea in how to show `()` rather than `NIL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expressions `nil`, `'nil`, `()`, and `'()` all gets evaluated to `nil` which is displayed as `nil` unless it is the `cdr` of a pair in which it will just close the list. eg. `'(() . ())` gets evaluated to `(NIL . NIL)` and it is displayed as `(NIL)`. There is nothing you can do about that.

So the question is then, because `((a) (()) (c))` is really `((a . nil) . ((nil . nil) . ((c . nil) . nil)))` should it count `nil`/`()` 5 times or ignore when `nil` in the `cdr` of a pair and just count it as one?

BTW using `setq` in `countOccurencesAll` on undefined bindings means your code is in the mercy of the implementation. The hyperspec does not define how it should be handled and SBCL makes warnings about how it interprets the code and other might just choose an interpretation. A better approach would be to use `let` to define the bindings. Using a hash and iterate over the list once would make an O(n) solution.

Comment: Hi, Sylwester. I looked a little bit about using setq and let and changed the function to use let. In relation to NIL, it really doesn't seem to make sense to count NIL referring to pairs cdr. Thus, I think that just changing the use of setq by let already solves my problem. I will investigate the use of hashes in lisp as well. Thank you for your answer! :)